# How can I sort facebook feeds by "caption"?

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have this JSON data from my facebook page:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1234567890_0987654321", 
      "from": {
        "name": "My Facebook Page", 
        "category": "Personal blog", 
        "id": "1234567890"
      }, 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1234567890/posts/0987654321"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1234567890/posts/0987654321"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Action Name", 
          "link": "http://example.com/"
        }
      ], 
      "message": "This post discusses something about Javascript.", 
      "name": "A post about javascript.", 
      "link": "http://example.com/", 
      "caption": "JavaScript", 
      "description": "Something telling about the post.", 
      "created_time": "2012-10-09T03:35:22+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "1234567890_0987654321", 
      "from": {
        "name": "My Facebook Page", 
        "category": "Personal blog", 
        "id": "1234567890"
      }, 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1234567890/posts/0987654321"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1234567890/posts/0987654321"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Action Name", 
          "link": "http://example.com/"
        }
      ], 
      "message": "This post discusses something about CSS.", 
      "name": "A post about CSS.", 
      "link": "http://example.com/", 
      "caption": "CSS", 
      "description": "Something telling about the post.", 
      "created_time": "2012-10-09T03:35:22+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anyway I can do this with FQL where I will just have all the posts with `"caption": "JavaScript"`? I want to sort my post by category and my keywords are inside the `"caption"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to get feeds short by order you need to use `FQL`
here is sample one of them

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id,description, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()  order by description
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who responded my question. I think I got the answer to my question already.

I will just do this query on FQL to get all posts with `"caption": "Javascript"`:

```
SELECT actor_id,message,attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id=1234567890 AND attachment.caption="Javascript"
```